# Problem with function DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

Please help me fix the error:

```
DSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.
DSolve[eqn,u,x]
solves a differential equation for the function u, with independent variable x.
```

```
Subscript[ξ, ρ][ρ_, t_] = D[v[ρ, t], ρ];
Subscript[ξ, ϕ][ρ_, t_] = v[ρ, t]/ρ;

Subscript[σ, ρ][ρ_, t_] = 
  Integrate[
   G*(2*D[Subscript[ξ, ρ][ρ, t], 
        t] + (κ - 
         1)*(D[Subscript[ξ, ρ][ρ, t], t] + 
         D[Subscript[ξ, ϕ][ρ, t], t])), t];
Subscript[σ, ϕ][ρ_, t_] = 
  Integrate[
   G*((κ + 1)*
       D[Subscript[ξ, ϕ][ρ, t], t] + (κ - 1)*
       D[Subscript[ξ, ρ][ρ, t], t]), t];
D[D[Subscript[σ, ρ][ρ, t], t], ρ] + (
   D[Subscript[σ, ρ][ρ, t], t] - 
    D[Subscript[σ, ϕ][ρ, t], t])/ρ == 
  0 // FullSimplify
D[Subscript[σ, ρ][b[t], t], t] + q[t] == 
  0 // FullSimplify
DSolve[{-D[v[ρ, t], 
       t] + ρ *(D[D[v[ρ, t], ρ], t] + ρ* 
         D[D[D[v[ρ, t], ρ], ρ], t]) == 0, 
   G *(-1 + κ)*(D[v[b[t], t], t] + 
        D[b[t], t]*D[v[b[t], t], b[t]]) + 
     b[t]*(q[t] + 
        G *(1 + κ)*(D[D[v[b[t], t], b[t]], t] + 
           D[b[t], t]* D[D[v[b[t], t], b[t]], b[t]])) == (
    G *(-1 + κ)*v[b[t], t]*D[b[t], t])/b[t]}, 
  v, {ρ, t}] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: The odes include expressions `v[\[Rho], t]` (ok)  and `v[b[t], t]` (not ok)

Comment: b(t) - this is some function that I cannot explicitly set. I will then analyze her behavior depending on t.

Comment: I think `DSolve` cannot handle that.

Comment: Ulrich Neumann, please give me a recommendation on what function to use here?

Comment: Sorry no idea, but I didn't understand your purpose yet

Comment: You try to solve two pdes for one function `v`, how should it be possible?

Comment: Ulrich Neumann, I added a plan of what I want to accomplish, written in code.

Comment: I tried writing what I could from your image, [does this look right](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/31399985-310c-4641-a659-19cc8fd315dd) ? I did not incorporate the final b.c. $\sigma_\rho(b(t),t) = - q(t)$ because I couldn't quite understand the definition of $q(t)$

Comment: @Mark I'm missing the definition of `\[Sigma]\[Phi] [\[Rho], t]` . It seeem to be a mechanical problem. From the equilibrium equation you should get  a context between  `\[Sigma]\[Phi]` and  `\[Sigma]\[Rho]` which finally gives one pde in `v`

Comment: @ydd, functions should depend on the rho variable and the t parameter. (written at the bottom of my picture). In order to reduce confusion, let's skip the definition of q[t], then the second condition will be written as: dotsigmarho[b[t],t]=-q[t]. We consider q[t] and b[t] to be known functions, that is, v can be expressed through them, but they are not explicitly specified.

Comment: I tried to insert this condition into the system:'''vSol[\[Rho]_, t_] = DSolveValue[{eq1, v[a, t] == ​​0, dotSigmaRho[b, t] == ​​-q}, v[\[Rho], t], {\[Rho], t}] // FullSimplify''', but I got the error:'''DSolveValue::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential or integral equations of the given functions'''. Since, as I understand it, dotsigmarho and dotsigmaphi are defined as variables, and not as functions.

Comment: @Mark I just added second B.C. to [the notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/31399985-310c-4641-a659-19cc8fd315dd). I couldn't get it to work with $\rho=b(t)$ , and instead had to have a fixed $b$ like $\dot{\sigma}_\rho(b,t) = -q(t)$